# how to change spark worker URL change in master UI?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-standalone

I want to change external URL of spark worker in spark master user currently i am using docker server for same.Any one have idea what can i do for same ? Any parameter that i have to pass in docker compose file ?

I also attach screenshot of my spark master page.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR8hq.png)